# Mule: Keep track of the message type

Tags: mule

Is there an "easy" way to track/know what the message type is at a given point in the flow (plus any additional message property)? 
Thinking about branching and sub-flows, I find it very difficult to keep track of the message and it's properties.
I could probably investigate each message processor / transformer along the way to figure out what the message type is but I am wondering if there is a better way. Maybe there is something already built-in with MuleStudio that I don't know about?

thanks, Markus

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [**logger**](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE3STUDIO/Logger+Component+Reference) component? It shows the message payload type, message properties, payload content, etc. You can also configure the log level you need.